# How to change the source file in PlatformIO?

Tags: c++, ini, platformio

I'm using Platform IO in the default project structure.
But how can I change the `main.cpp` to another name like `main_client.cpp`? Is there any `.ini` flag to set this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just have to rename the file in place. What is your trouble ?

Comment: I want to use this because I have two main files for two Arduinos, but this both use the same headers, so I want to have it in one project.